# Resizable and draggable together not respecting containment

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I want to have an image that is draggable and resizable (from all handles), but when the image is resized from one of the left handles, the containment is not respected anymore when the image is dragged (e.g: the image can be taken out of the container). Why is this happening and what can I do about it?

Code is below, and jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/F4c8p/

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
       <head>
          <meta charset="utf-8"/>
          <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
          <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
          <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
          <script>
              $(function() {
                 $( "#draggable" ).draggable({
                    containment: '#container'
                 });
                 $('#resizable').resizable({
                    containment: '#container',
                    handles: 'all'
                 });
              });
          </script>
       </head>
       <body>
          <div style="width: 800px; height: 600px; border: 1px solid black" id="container">
             <div id="draggable" style="display:inline-block">    
                <img id="resizable"  src="http://www.extremetech.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/image-1.jpg"/> 
             </div>
          </div>
       </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Try loading your image before the java script code.. so that way the image loads first.. does that make sense? Here is a jsfiddle someone else did: http://jsfiddle.net/VKe5h/

Comment: can I get some feedback on my answer?

Answer (score 0):

What is happening is that when you resize anywhere but the bottom right is that the drag gable position is no longer lined up with the re sizable image.  So I added some code to line the drag gable and the image up.

Once the image has been dragged it seems to lose its containment when re-sizing.  Like if you resize the image small and then bring the image to the bottom right and expand it there is no longer containment.  But this behavior is reproducible in your original fiddle as well.

```
$(function() {

    $( ".draggable" ).draggable({
        containment: '#container'
    });

    $('#resizable').resizable({
        containment: '#container',
        handles: 'all',
        stop: function(event, ui) {
            var draggable = ui.helper.closest('.draggable'); 
            var dragPos = draggable.position();
            var left = dragPos.left + ui.position.left;
            var top = dragPos.top + ui.position.top;
            draggable.css('left',left+'px');
            draggable.find('.ui-wrapper').css('left','auto');
            draggable.css('top',top+'px');
            draggable.find('.ui-wrapper').css('top','auto');
        }
    });
});
```

Example

http://jsfiddle.net/trevordowdle/F4c8p/2/

Comment: @luqita can I get some feedback on my answer?  Thanks